# BRST invariant vertex operator

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, brst

I'm trying to compute the commutator $\left[Q_{BRST}(z), V^{-1/2}_{v}(w)\right]$, where $V^{-1/2}_{v}(w)$ is the vertex operator corresponding to a massive fermion state. The vertex reads

$$
V_{v}^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\Lambda_{c a} v^{\alpha} e^{-\varphi / 2} S_{\alpha} \partial Z^{1} e^{\frac{i}{2} H_{1}} e^{-\frac{i}{2} H_{2}} e^{-\frac{i}{2} H_{3}} e^{i k X}
$$

The BRST charge takes the form

$$
Q_{B R S T}=\int e^{\varphi / 2} \eta\left[\partial X_{\mu} \psi^{\mu}+\sum_{I=1}^{3} \partial Z^{I} e^{-i H_{I}}+\sum_{I=1}^{3} \partial \bar{Z}^{I} e^{i H_{I}}\right].
$$

I already know, that the next step should look as follows

$$
{\left[Q_{B R S T}(z), V_{v}^{-\frac{1}{2}}(w)\right]=v_{\alpha} \oint_{w} \frac{z}{2 \pi i} \eta e^{\varphi / 2}(z-w)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \times\left(\frac{\sigma_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}^{\mu} S^{\dot{\alpha}}(z)}{(z-w)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{k_{\mu}}{(z-w)} \partial Z^{1} e^{\frac{i}{2} H_{1}}+S^{\alpha} \frac{(z-w)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(z-w)^{2}} e^{\frac{3 i}{2} H_{1}}\right) e^{-\frac{i}{2} H_{2}} e^{-\frac{i}{2} H_{3}} e^{i k X}
$$

where some of the following OPE's have been used:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
e^{q_{1} \varphi(z)} e^{q_{2} \varphi(w)} \sim(z-w)^{-q_{1} q_{2}} e^{\left(q_{1}+q_{2}\right) \varphi(w)} \\
e^{i r_{1} H(z)} e^{i r_{2} H(w)} \sim(z-w)^{r_{1} r_{2}} e^{i\left(r_{1}+r_{2}\right) H(w)} \\
\psi^{\mu}(z) \psi^{\nu}(w) \sim \frac{\eta^{\mu \nu}}{(z-w)} \\
\partial^{\mu} X(z) e^{i k X(w)} \sim-\frac{2 i \alpha^{\prime} k^{\mu}}{z-w} e^{i k X(w)} \\
\psi^{\mu}(z) S_{\alpha}(w) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\sigma_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}^{\mu} C^{\dot{\alpha}}(w)}{(z-w)^{1 / 2}} \\
\psi_{\mu}(z) C^{\dot{\alpha}}(w) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\bar{\sigma}_{\mu}^{\dot{\alpha} \alpha} S_{\alpha}(w)}{(z-w)^{1 / 2}} \\
\psi^{\mu}(z) S_{\alpha}\left(w_{1}\right) C_{\dot{\alpha}}\left(w_{2}\right) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\sigma_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}^{\mu}}{\left(z-w_{1}\right)^{1 / 2}\left(z-w_{2}\right)^{1 / 2}}
\end{array}
$$

However, I cannot come up with the desired solution (especially the 2nd term). I'm currently solving it in Mathematica, where it's easy, but a bit of cheating (by inserting the OPE's). Would be extremely happy if someone can find a clean and formal way to solve that step.

UPDATE: $H_{I}$ is a bosonic field ($\rightarrow$ Bosonization) and $v^{\alpha}$ a Weyl-Spinor

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the context of this computation? There are several unclear statements in your question. A sample of them: 1)  When you write "a massive fermion state $\alpha_{-1}^{1}|0\rangle_{R}$" its not clear what you want. The notation $\alpha_{-1}^{1}|0\rangle_{R}$ means "the state associated to the component one of the Virasoro's bosonic $\alpha_{-1}^{1}$ creation operator acting on the Ramond vacua". 2) Concerning $V_{v}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. I'm not sure that the expression you write is the correct one, Do you have a reference where this is computed?

Comment: What are $H_{1},H_{2},H_{3}$, What the symbol "$V_{v}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$" means? I suppose that $v$ is a vector that satisfy $\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}v=0$, but I'm not sure. It would be great that you provide a reference just to be sure about your notation.

Comment: Thank you for the help @RamiroHum-Sah. It's around page 9 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.07584.pdf

Comment: why do you say that inserting the ope’s is cheating? these ope’s are exact (when you include the Taylor expansion terms you’ve dropped) within their radius of convergence, which in turn corresponds to the closest other operator insertion. i’m not sure about your power of $\varphi$ in the final answer, but doesn’t the second term in the commutator come from contracting the last term in Q_B with the vertex op? I’m assuming you’ve gone through similar computations for the easier massless cases, bosonic string, etc., right?

Comment: @Wakabaloola The goal of this computation is to get information about first and second order poles. In my code, I do that by comparing the coefficients. That's fine, but I would like to see it in a clean and more formal way. (Radial ordering, etc.). Btw that was obviously my first guess too, but somehow it is not just the contraction...

Comment: @NathanaelNoir i’m not sure where the problem lies, but have you tried writing down all possible contractions? you don’t need mathematica.

Comment: @Wakabaloola you're right - not for that case, but I'm coding that for a more general and harder case. I just wanted to see, how it works in that case in a very formal way. Including Radial/Normal ordering, which in the most books is omitted.

Comment: @NathanaelNoir Radial ordering is essentially always included (unless you use the honest path integral without cft along the lines of weinberg) when using these cft techniques. polchinski certainly goes through the relevant concepts extremely carefully, and correctly. Ginsparg’s cft lecture notes from 1987-88 (?) include radial ordering in the notation also which is always there but often implicit. i’m still not sure where the problem is?

Comment: @NathanaelNoir see sec.2.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028 to see why the radial ordering procedure gives the procedure based on computing all wick contractions and carrying out the corresponding contour integrals